# anchor program not getting build

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang

here is my code, I'm using `anchor 0.26.0`.
I'm getting some error while building

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod counter {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let count = &mut ctx.accounts.count;
        count.count = 0;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn increment(ctx: Context<Increment>) -> Result<()> {
        let count = &mut ctx.accounts.count;
        count.count += 1;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn decrement(ctx: Context<Decrement>) -> Result<()> {
        let count = &mut ctx.accounts.count;
        count.count -= 1;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info>{
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = Count::SIZE)]
    pub count: Account<'info, Count>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Increment<'info>{
    #[account(mut)]
    pub count: Account<'info, Count>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Decrement<'info>{
    #[account(mut)]
    pub count: Account<'info, Count>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Count{
    pub count: i32,
}

impl Count{
    pub const SIZE: usize = 8 + 4;
}
```

and error:

```
Error: Function _ZN94_$LT$$RF$mut$u20$bincode..de..Deserializer$LT$R$C$O$GT$$u20$as$u20$serde..de..Deserializer$GT$17deserialize_tuple17hc95988d4434a0508E Stack offset of 11472 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 7376 bytes, please minimize large stack variables

Error: Function _ZN14solana_program4vote5state9VoteState11deserialize17h8b2a261739cdf8a8E Stack offset of 5664 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 1568 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
```

how do I fix it?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the more recent solana releases. Check out this [answer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/5690/1202). Usually you can just ignore it. Is it actually affecting your program's ability to run?

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to an incompatibility between the latest versions of anchor and Solana.

Try forcing an older version of Solana in `Cargo.toml`. Curious if this works.

```
[workspace.dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.26.0"
anchor-spl = "0.26.0"
solana-program = "=1.14.14"
```

Comment: this works ! (i used solana program 1.14.12)

Comment: hey, I added this, still it's fetching solana-program v1.15.2

Comment: I scaffolded a project and added the above code, still it's compiling with version `1.15.2`

Comment: so I had to add more line to make compile with `v1.14.14`.
I added these line
`[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { workspace = true}
solana-program = { workspace = true}
`