# Getting error while running cargo build-bpf

Tags: error, cargo, build-bpf

I was trying to compile this contract but ended up getting this error

**Error**
Error: Function *ZN14solana_program4vote5state9VoteState11deserialize17hdfad8c2762e760a5E Stack offset of 6344 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 2248 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function *ZN229*$LT$solana_program..vote..state..vote_state_0_23_5..*..$LT$impl$u20$serde..de..Deserialize$u20$for$u20$solana_program..vote..state..vote_state_0_23_5..VoteState0_23_5$GT$..deserialize..__Visitor$u20$as$u20$serde..de..Visitor$GT$9visit_seq17h40cd23801379c52cE Stack offset of 5752 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 1656 bytes, please minimize large stack variables

**Contract**
use solana_program::{
account_info::AccountInfo, entrypoint, entrypoint::ProgramResult, msg, pubkey::Pubkey,
};

entrypoint!(process_instruction);
fn process_instruction(
program_id: &Pubkey,
accounts: &[AccountInfo],
instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
msg!(
"process_instruction: {}: {} accounts, data={:?}",
program_id,
accounts.len(),
instruction_data
);
Ok(())
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack offset error for anchor build](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5651/stack-offset-error-for-anchor-build)